# spring edit form not retaining datefields

Tags: java, spring-mvc

i am trying to perform an update operation using spring form. there are few fields in my entity which are not bound on the spring form(date fields: createdDate, modifiedDate). But when i submit the form, the date fields become null on controller. I have tried using form:hidden field but that too is not retaining the datefields on submit of form. Pls help
    here is my entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PORTAL_SUPPLIER")
public class PortalSupplier extends AbstractEntity implements Serializable {
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2187090408756348981L;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "SUPP_ID")
    @TableGenerator(table = "PORTAL_TABLE_GENERATOR", name = "TABLE_SEQ_GENERATOR", pkColumnValue = "SUPP_ID",allocationSize = 1, initialValue = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE, generator = "TABLE_SEQ_GENERATOR")
    private int supplierId;

    @Column(name = "TIN_NUM", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String tinNumber;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_NAME", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String supplierName;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_ADDRESS", nullable = true, length = 500)
    private String supplierAddress;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_EMAIL_ID", nullable = true, length = 100)
    private String supplierEmailId;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_PHONE_NUM", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String supplierPhoneNumber;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_MOBILE_NUM", nullable = true, length = 20)
    private String supplierMobileNumber;

    @Column(name = "SUPP_ACTIVE_FLAG", nullable = false, length = 1)
    private String supplierActive;

    @Column(name = "MONTH", nullable = false, length = 2)
    private int month;

    @Column(name = "YEAR", nullable = false, length = 4)
    private int year;

    /**
     * @return the supplierId
     */
    public int getSupplierId() {
        return supplierId;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierId the supplierId to set
     */
    public void setSupplierId(int supplierId) {
        this.supplierId = supplierId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the tinNumber
     */
    public String getTinNumber() {
        return tinNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param tinNumber the tinNumber to set
     */
    public void setTinNumber(String tinNumber) {
        this.tinNumber = tinNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierName
     */
    public String getSupplierName() {
        return supplierName;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierName the supplierName to set
     */
    public void setSupplierName(String supplierName) {
        this.supplierName = supplierName;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierAddress
     */
    public String getSupplierAddress() {
        return supplierAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierAddress the supplierAddress to set
     */
    public void setSupplierAddress(String supplierAddress) {
        this.supplierAddress = supplierAddress;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierEmailId
     */
    public String getSupplierEmailId() {
        return supplierEmailId;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierEmailId the supplierEmailId to set
     */
    public void setSupplierEmailId(String supplierEmailId) {
        this.supplierEmailId = supplierEmailId;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierPhoneNumber
     */
    public String getSupplierPhoneNumber() {
        return supplierPhoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierPhoneNumber the supplierPhoneNumber to set
     */
    public void setSupplierPhoneNumber(String supplierPhoneNumber) {
        this.supplierPhoneNumber = supplierPhoneNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierMobileNumber
     */
    public String getSupplierMobileNumber() {
        return supplierMobileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierMobileNumber the supplierMobileNumber to set
     */
    public void setSupplierMobileNumber(String supplierMobileNumber) {
        this.supplierMobileNumber = supplierMobileNumber;
    }

    /**
     * @return the supplierActive
     */
    public String getSupplierActive() {
        return supplierActive;
    }

    /**
     * @param supplierActive the supplierActive to set
     */
    public void setSupplierActive(String supplierActive) {
        this.supplierActive = supplierActive;
    }

    /**
     * @return the month
     */
    public int getMonth() {
        return month;
    }

    /**
     * @param month the month to set
     */
    public void setMonth(int month) {
        this.month = month;
    }

    /**
     * @return the year
     */
    public int getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    /**
     * @param year the year to set
     */
    public void setYear(int year) {
        this.year = year;
    }

}
```

Here is my abstractbaseentity

```
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AbstractEntity  {

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE_CREATED", nullable = false)
    private Date dateCreated;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @Column(name = "DATE_MODIFIED", nullable =false)
    private Date dateModified;

    @PrePersist
    @PreUpdate
    private void updateDate(){
        dateModified = new Date();
    }

    /**
     * @return the dateCreated
     */
    public Date getDateCreated() {
        return dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateCreated the dateCreated to set
     */
    public void setDateCreated(Date dateCreated) {
        this.dateCreated = dateCreated;
    }

    /**
     * @return the dateModified
     */
    public Date getDateModified() {
        return dateModified;
    }

    /**
     * @param dateModified the dateModified to set
     */
    public void setDateModified(Date dateModified) {
        this.dateModified = dateModified;
    }
}
```

Here is my edit form

```html
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Add Supplier</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form:form method="post" modelAttribute="supplier" id="addSupplierForm">
        <table border="0">
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="tinNumber">TIN NUMBER</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="tinNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="supplierName">SUPPLIER NAME</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="supplierName" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="supplierAddress">SUPPLIER ADDRESS</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="supplierAddress" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="supplierEmailId">SUPPLIER EMAIL ID</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="supplierEmailId" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="supplierPhoneNumber">SUPPLIER PHONE NUMBER</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="supplierPhoneNumber" /></td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="supplierMobileNumber">SUPPLIER MOBILE NUMBER</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="supplierMobileNumber" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="month">MONTH</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="month" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><form:label path="year">YEAR</form:label></td>
                <td><form:input path="year" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="SUBMIT"></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td><form:hidden path="supplierActive"/></td>
            <td><form:hidden path="dateCreated"/></td>
            <td><form:hidden path="dateModified"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>


    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Provide the content of your view (JSP) which will be handled by Spring MVC and creates your entity.

Comment: apologies for bad formatting as this is my first post here and just learning to add codes and htmls seperately. in the code block itself, i have added the view jsp as well. you may please scroll down and check for the same. TIA

Comment: I fixed your code formatting. For current and future posts, please only provide the necessary data to replicate the problem. Also, you can edit the question to see how the code is formatted for future questions.

Comment: Well, you state that `dateCreated` and `dateModified` are hidden fields which have no value **at all**, and HTTP is a stateless protocol. In the end, the values in the `<form>` for these fields is empty, which Spring MVC will threat as `null` values, hence your *issue*.

Comment: thanks for your inputs, but the "supplierActive" field in the form is also used as a hidden field and i have not specified any value for it the form, but still it successfully retains my DB value succesfuly on form submit. But why the datefields alone not behaving that way. any pointer would be deeply appreciated.

Comment: Well, two things: 1) Are you sure these fields are filled before creating the view? 2) Do you know the differences between `String` and primitive types (`int`, `char`, etc...) and a `Date` and understand they behave way different?

Comment: 1) yes its bound before rendering the view. 2) yes i do understand these types.